# How to set a filesystem type without losing data?

Tags: filesystem

I have my 2TB external HDD that was working perfectly. Now it won't auto mount or manually mount. I keep receiving errors telling me that I have the wrong filesystem type.

Is there a way to set a filesystem type without losing all my data?

Comment: How do you moint it manually ?

Answer (score 0):

You can not convert the file system without formatting your hard drive.

Plug-in your extarnal drive and open your computer with live Ubuntu CD/USB with the TRY option. Check the disks utility from your dash and look for the external drive in the list of disks utility.

If you can see the drive then you can execute self tests or benchmark test;

else if it was not there; try to change the connection cable;

else if you tried on another computer and is working, your operating system should be cleaned from the old system files.

else if, format it.

Comment: Will the `mkfs` command reformat my drive then?

Comment: mkfs is used for Linux filesystems. Is your hdd was formatted as ext3,ext4 or sth. like these?

Comment: My hdd was originally fat32, but now it doesn't seem to have one. Below is a link to my original question and explains the step by step process and the errors I am receiving. [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/372791/how-do-i-mount-my-external-hdd-with-filesystem-type-errors)

Comment: Please try sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdb and also look through http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2160542

Comment: So I tried what you had recommended and what was on your provided link and it still isn't working.

`pj@PJ:~$ sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdb
Mounting volume... NTFS signature is missing.
FAILED
Attempting to correct errors... NTFS signature is missing.
FAILED
Failed to startup volume: Invalid argument
NTFS signature is missing.
Trying the alternate boot sector
Unrecoverable error
Volume is corrupt. You should run chkdsk.`

Comment: When I run `sudo fdisk -l` here are my results.

`Disk /dev/sdb: 2000.4 GB, 2000365289472 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243197 cylinders, total 3906963456 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00041e29

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1              63  3906959804  1953479871    b  W95 FAT32`

Answer (score -2):

If there is any bugs on the Linux kernel, it shows "wrong filesystem type" error when you connect USB or external HDD to the pc. Run the below command on the terminal to update your Linux kernel.

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic
```

Once the kernel is successfully installed, reboot your PC.